# problema con condicional con números decimales y enteros

Tags: php

Buenas,

Estoy teniendo un problema que no sé la forma de resolverlo, y que tampoco entiendo el motivo por el que no me funciona. Tengo un pequeño código que de varios precios, me saca el más barato. Al tratarse de distintos paises hay que convertirlos a una moneda en concreto, hasta aquí todo bien. El código además resalta en otro color el precio más barato con la bandera del país.

Os dejo el código:

```
$valor_minimo = calcula_valor_minimo($posts[0], $moneda_a_mostrar);



foreach ($posts as $post) {

                        if (empty($valor_minimo)) {
                                echo "<p class='precio'><img class='fondo_precio_izquierda' src='imagenes/degradado.png' ><img class='cuarto' src='" . $posts[0]['URL_imagen'] . "'>-</p>";
                        } else {

                        $paises = ['Espanya', 'USA', 'Brasil',
                                        'Canada', 'Colombia', 'Hong_Kong',
                                        'Hungria', 'Rusia', 'Singapur',
                                        'Sudafrica', 'Mexico', 'Argentina',
                                        'Australia', 'Chile', 'China',
                                        'India', 'Inglaterra', 'Japon',
                                        'Korea', 'Taiwan'
                                    ];

                        $sal_bucle = 0;
                        $pais_mas_barato = "";    

                        foreach ($paises as $pais) {

                            $divisa = "divisa_" . str_replace("_","",strtolower($pais));
                            $pais_oferta = $pais . "_Oferta";
                            $pais_gold = $pais . "_Gold";

                            if ($post["$pais_oferta"] == "-" AND $post["$pais_gold"] == "-") {
                                if (number_format($post["$pais"]*$$divisa,2,'.','') == $valor_minimo AND $sal_bucle == 0) {
                                    $pais_mas_barato = $pais;
                                    $sal_bucle = 1;
                                }
                            } else if ($post["$pais_oferta"] != "-") {
                                if (number_format($post["$pais_oferta"]*$$divisa,2,'.','') == $valor_minimo AND $sal_bucle == 0) {
                                    $pais_mas_barato = $pais;
                                    $sal_bucle = 1;
                                }
                            } else if ($post["$pais_gold"] != "-") {
                                if (number_format($post["$pais_gold"]*$$divisa,2,'.','') == $valor_minimo AND $sal_bucle == 0) {
                                    $pais_mas_barato = $pais;
                                    $sal_bucle = 1;
                                }
                            }



                        }
```

Me pasa cuando entra en el siguiente condicional de los 3 que hay:

```
else if ($post["$pais_oferta"] != "-") {
     if (number_format($post["$pais_oferta"]*$$divisa,2,'.','') == $valor_minimo AND $sal_bucle == 0) {
         $pais_mas_barato = $pais;
         $sal_bucle = 1;
      }
}
```

Os pongo un ejemplo real de lo que me está pasando. El valor de la variable `$valor_minimo` es de 11102, y el valor del país donde está más barato 11102.00. Sin embargo no entra al condicional. Ya he comprobado que la variable `$sal_bucle` es 0.

He probado con este pequeño ejemplo y sin embargo sí que entra en el condicional:

```
if (11102.00 == 11102) {
    echo "hola";
}
```

No entiendo qué estoy haciendo mal. Los decimales los necesito, he intentado que la variable `$valor_minimo` tenga también decimales con el siguiente código:

```
$valor_minimo = number_format($valor_minimo,2,'.','');
```

Pero me devuelve un error:

> A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: tienes  dos $ en divisa en tu if

Comment: @JorgeArturoJuarez Es una variable, si te fijas antes delas condicionales declaro esa y otras.

Comment: ok, si ya vi, Variable variable...  que te responde un dump_var en tu $valor_minimo y en $$divisa?

Answer (score -2):

Prueba a poner delante un `(float)`:

```
(float)(number_format($post["$pais_oferta"]*$$divisa,2,'.',''));
```

Actualiza tu pregunta indicando qué valor es `$post["$pais_oferta"]`

¿El valor de `$post["$pais_oferta"]` es un integer?